# jQuery, .html, add a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, shopping-cart

I'm trying to add a div with some details of a discount coupon so the user can confirm it before I add it to the shopping cart.

The code to the button etc... is this, and it works if I place on the website:

```
<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem"><h1 class="item_name">Discount of 30%!</h1><a href="javascript:;" class="item_add">Confirm Coupon!</a><span class="item_price" >0.00€</span></div>
```

Then, I tried to dynamically add the code (when a php post confirms that the coupon code is OK) using jQuery, but by some strange reason it doesn't work.

I managed to write this:

```
$('div.cupao_confirm').html('<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem"><h1 class="item_name">Discount of 30%!</h1><a href="javascript:;" class="item_add">Confirm Coupon!</a><span class="item_price" >0.00€</span></div>');
```

Without jQuery the code add the "0.00€" product to the shopping cart, so I can later send the equivalent money back to the buyer. With jQuery when I click on the link nothing happens at all. So it's not a jQuery related problem... I might be doing the .html() wrong... :( help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the `append()` method :

```
$('div.cupao_confirm').append("<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem"><h1 class="item_name">Discount of 30%!</h1><a href="javascript:;" class="item_add">Confirm Coupon!</a><span class="item_price" >0.00€</span></div>");
```

Give it a try and let me know if it worked, Thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry I can't "vote up" you now, but anyway, I've tried that and no luck too.. :(

Comment: The button appears using the .html or .append, but when I click on it nothing happens at all. `code` $('div.cupao_confirm').append('<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem"><h1 class="item_name">Discount of 30%!</h1><a href="javascript:;" class="item_add">Confirm Coupon!</a><span class="item_price" >0.00€</span></div>');

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you need to re-initialize simple cart ager changing the shell contents.  Try:

```
            simpleCart.init();
```